# How to bind a key such that it toggles between one particular application and the current application?

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys

I want to bind a key such that a particular application (in my case Pidgin or Calculator) gets the focus, then when I am done and press key again, the focus returns to the previously focused application, as though I never changed focus.

For example:

**Before:**

> Chromium —<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>→ Files —<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>→ Chromium

**Use of key binding:**

> Chromium —<kbd>(bound key)</kbd>→ Pidgin (answer to chat) or Calc (calculate something) —<kbd>(bound key)</kbd>→ Chromium

**After using above:**

> Chromium —<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>→ Files (not Pidgin) —<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>→ Chromium

Other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: You mean you want to replace the shortcut `ALT + Tab` by another one? Just tried it, but doesn't work for me either ..

Answer (score 0):

Toggling between two applications can be done, as you know, with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. But it's designed go through all of the open windows by Z-order; so every time a third application is activated, the Z-order changes and it's usually annoying to get the two apps you're mainly interested back in sync for switching.

I read your requirement to be that you have a main application Chromium and a secondary application, let's go with `gnome-calculator`, that you switch to frequently and would like a foolproof toggle between them using a single keybinding.

You can, however, create this behavior with a script and a custom keybinding. To create the script, I wanted something simple (for me) to understand and that could be easily modified without compiling; so I used python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gtk
import re
import sys
import time
import wnck

#windows are found through the titlebar, not the app name
#edit the titles to change the apps
titlePrimaryApp = re.compile(".*Chromium*")
titleSecondaryApp = re.compile("Calculator")

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

#needed for the code that gets the windows list to work
while gtk.events_pending():
  gtk.main_iteration()

active_window = screen.get_active_window()
open_windows = screen.get_windows()

#if the primary app is already activated, find the secondary app, and activate it
if titlePrimaryApp.match(active_window.get_name()):
  for w in open_windows:
    if titleSecondaryApp.match(w.get_name()):
      w.activate(int(time.time()))

#otherwise, activate the primary app
else:
  for w in open_windows:
    if titlePrimaryApp.match(w.get_name()):
      w.activate(int(time.time()))
```

To use this script:

1. Save it in a file such as `myswitcher.py`. A good place for it is `/home/<user>/bin`.
2. Make it executable: `chmod +x myswitcher.py`
3. You will need: `sudo apt-get install python-wnck`. This is the library that works with Gtk windows. It is not installed by default.
4. Link the script to a keybinding.

   The easiest way to do this is to create a custom shortcut in `System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Custom Shortcuts`.
5. After highlighting *Custom Shortcuts* in the list on the left, click the plus sign to add a shortcut.
6. In the popup window, choose a name for the shortcut and enter the command `/path/to/myswitcher.py`.
7. The new shortcut will be added to the list of shortcuts in the window. To the right of the name will be the word *disabled*. Set the keybinding by clicking the word *disabled*, then typing the key combination that you want.
8. Make sure you choose a keybinding that doesn't conflict with other programs. Those bindings are set at a lower level and will preempt the script. I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>\</kbd>  (backslash) since it is not used by anything else and is more or less the mirror image of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (at least on my keyboard layout).
9. You need to log out and log back in before the custom keybinding will work.

Credit for help with the script:

I had most of the script logic worked out before looking around for examples (and there's no shortage of `wnck` examples out there); but I need to credit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776978/python-wnck-set-focus-to-window) on StackOverflow that solved some problems I was having with the regular expressions usage, the syntax for passing in the gtk timestamp, and most importantly providing the key lines about the Gtk events. Without those 2 lines, get_windows returns an empty list.